# Trying to use SpeechRecognizer (Android speech recognition) but it's not starting?

Tags: android, android-studio, speech-recognition

Here's my code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_route);

    SetupButton();

}

private void SetupButton()
{
    Button createNewMessage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    createNewMessage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ListenForNewMessage();
        }
    });
}

private void ListenForNewMessage()
{
    final SpeechRecognizer newDeliverySpeech = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this);
    RecognitionListener newDeliveryRecognitionListener = new RecognitionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle params) {
            Log.d("SpeechListening","onReadyForSpeech");
        }
        @Override
        public void onBeginningOfSpeech() {
            Log.d("SpeechListening","onBeginningOfSpeech");
        }

        @Override
        public void onRmsChanged(float rmsdB) {
            //do nothing
        }

        @Override
        public void onBufferReceived(byte[] buffer) {
            //do nothing
        }

        @Override
        public void onEndOfSpeech() {
            Log.d("SpeechListening","onEndOfSpeech");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(int error) {
            //do nothing
        }

        @Override
        public void onResults(Bundle results) {
            ArrayList<String> userMessage;
            userMessage = results.getStringArrayList(RESULTS_RECOGNITION);
            PushNewDelivery(userMessage);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPartialResults(Bundle partialResults) {
            //do nothing
        }

        @Override
        public void onEvent(int eventType, Bundle params) {
            //do nothing
        }
    };
    newDeliverySpeech.setRecognitionListener(newDeliveryRecognitionListener);
    if (newDeliverySpeech.isRecognitionAvailable(getApplicationContext()))
    {
        Log.d("SpeechListening","started listening hopefully");
        newDeliverySpeech.startListening(new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH));
    }
}
```

}

The problem is, only the **started listening hopefully** is logged, the `RecognitionListener` never has `onReadyForSpeech()` or any of its methods called.

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

*You can change this below line*

```
newDeliverySpeech.startListening(new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH));
```

*To,*

```
 Intent mSpeechIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    mSpeechIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    mSpeechIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PARTIAL_RESULTS, true);
    mSpeechIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE, "voice.recognition.test");
    mSpeechIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 1);
    newDeliverySpeech.startListening(mSpeechIntent);
```

Comment: Nope, no change. In the documentation it says that it's fine to leave the intent as default

Answer (score 0):

Ask the user for the permission to record audio before calling `startListening`:

```
String[] permissions = {Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO};
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permissions, REQUEST_RECORD_AUDIO_PERMISSION);
```

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediarecorder#audio-record-permission